# Reference in modeling language

Tags: hyperledger-composer

This will not create a reference loop in modeling language, right?

```
participant Owner identified by name {
    o String name
    o Car[] cars
}

asset Car identified by plateNumber {
    o String plateNumber 
    --> Owner owner
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct - it won't. Your model simply creates an array of `cars` in participant class `Owner` and a relationship (identifier) to `owner` from the asset class `Car`. This is perfectly fine and reasonable as for as modeling goes and the circular nature of what you're asking.